# An improved way to retrieve values from Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary with an int key and the value is an instance of a class called `MachinePart`.

The key is significant to the what type of machine part the `MachinePart` is. For example, if the key is between `0-99` the machine part is in a category called "Free Movement". If the key is between `100-199`,the machine part is in another category and so on...

Therefore it is useful to have a method which will retrieve a certain category from the dictionary. To clarify to return a list of Machine Parts who keys are within a certain range.

Below is the code I currently have to retrieve the free movement parts. It works fine however I was wondering if there was a more improved way of writing this instead of having to have a loop which iterates 99 times.

```
 public static List<MachinePart> getFreeMovementParts(Dictionary<int, MachinePart> iMachineParts)
    {
        List<MachinePart> temp = new List<MachinePart>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        {
            MachinePart t;
            if (iMachineParts.TryGetValue(i, out t))
            {
                temp.Add(t);
            }
        }
        return temp;

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the `int` key used for? Without further information it sounds like using a `Dictonary` with an `enum` (for the category) as key and a `List<MachinePart>` as value might be a better solution

Comment: A standard dictionary assumes that teh keys are independent so there is no way of saying "Get all the values whose keys are in this range" without asking for each key separately as you have done. What you could do though is create a more complicated data structure optimised for your purposes. eg if your ints are all of the form nnxx then you could have a dictionary that had nn as a key and a list of parts as its value so you could get all the parts for category nn in one go. Whether this works will depend on your data but if not that something similar should be possible...

Comment: `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, MachinePart>>`, where the key of the first is `id / 100` and the key of the second is `id`.

Comment: To add to @Chris it's often not a bad solution to store the data in multiple representations. Maintaining two dictionaries, one as `id : MachinePart` and one as `categoryID : List<MachinePart>`, is often not a horrendous memory commitment. Obviously depends on your specific needs though.

Comment: You could probably get a "better looking" solution with some linq, but not in terms of rapidity. As the other said, you should probably think of a custom object that suit your needs. If you only have one level, @JeroenMostert solution is perfectly fine. If you need more levels, you can take a look to the composite pattern that allow a recursive tree structure.

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Linq to select the values as follows:

```
var freeMovementParts = iMachineParts.Where(it => it.Key >= 0 && it.Key <= 99)
                                     .Select(it => it.Value)
                                     .ToList();
```

But as suggested in the comments, it's better to think of an alternative data structure for the implementation. Also it is worth noting that iterating over the keys will lead to poor performance if the dictionary contains large number of items and you will lose the perf benefits of using the dictionary.

Comment: While this solution is more elegant at reading, it is not as performant as yours, especially if your dictionary contains a lot of items (it will loop over all the dictionary entries).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to Linq-ify your code you can do something like this:

```
    public static List<MachinePart> getFreeMovementParts(Dictionary<int, MachinePart> iMachineParts)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, 99)
            .Select(i => { iMachineParts.TryGetValue(i, out var mp); return mp; })
            .Where(mp => mp != null)
            .ToList();
    }
```

It does not solve problems mentioned in the comments, a different data structure might still be more appropriate, the above is mostly just for fun.

Performance of this approach vs performance of the "enumerate all keys" approach - it is similar to DB indexes, on a small data set it is often cheaper to do a full scan (enumerate all keys). But when you need only a small subset of items from a large dictionary - it will be cheaper to do the item lookups based on known range of keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var r = from part in iMachineParts
                where part.Key >= 0 && part.Key <= 99
                select part.Value;

        return r.ToList();
```